want to encrypt and decrypt audio file using PQC algo
So I have created two python files. They encrypt an audio file (input taken from user mic) using Kyber for KEM and then AES for the Encryption. Then the second file decrypts the same file.
With pure AES, the file sounds fine when decrypted. However with PQC the file still has noise even after decryption. The Codes are shown below. Any help would be greatly appreciated! (the files are run on libqos python on linux)

Encryption code

import pyaudio
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
import os
import wave
import oqs
# Step 1: Quantum-safe key exchange using Kyber512
kem_alg = "Kyber512"
kem = oqs.KeyEncapsulation(kem_alg)
# Generate post-quantum public and private key pair
public_key = kem.generate_keypair()
print(f"Public key (hex): {public_key.hex()}")
# Encapsulate a shared secret using the public key
ciphertext, shared_secret_enc = kem.encap_secret(public_key)
print(f"Ciphertext (hex): {ciphertext.hex()}")
print(f"Shared secret (encryption - hex): {shared_secret_enc.hex()}")
# Use shared secret as AES key
key = shared_secret_enc[:32]  # Use the first 32 bytes as the AES key
# Step 2: AES encryption setup
iv = os.urandom(16)  # Generate a random IV
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=default_backend())
encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
# Open the microphone stream
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=44100, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
# Open the output WAV file for writing encrypted data
with wave.open("quantum_safe_encrypted_audio.wav", "wb") as f:
    f.setnchannels(1)
    f.setsampwidth(2)
    f.setframerate(44100)
    # Write the IV and ciphertext (from the PQC key encapsulation) to the file (for decryption purposes)
    f.writeframes(iv)
    f.writeframes(ciphertext)
    # Padding setup for AES block size (16 bytes)
    padder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).padder()
    try:
        while True:
            data = stream.read(1024)
            # Encrypt the audio data
            padded_data = padder.update(data)
            ct = encryptor.update(padded_data)
            f.writeframes(ct)
            print("Writing encrypted audio data to file...")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Received keyboard interrupt. Stopping encryption.")
        # Finalize encryption with padding for the last block
        padded_data = padder.finalize()
        ct = encryptor.update(padded_data) + encryptor.finalize()
        f.writeframes(ct)
    # Close the microphone stream
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
print("Quantum-safe encrypted audio data written to quantum_safe_encrypted_audio.wav")



Decryption

import pyaudio
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import os
import wave
import hashlib
# Fixed key for AES encryption
original_key = b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x30\x31'
key = hashlib.sha256(original_key).digest()
print(key.hex())
#key = b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15'
# Open the encrypted audio file
with wave.open("quantum_safe_encrypted_audio.wav", "rb") as f:
    # Read the encrypted audio data
    encrypted_data = f.readframes(f.getnframes())
# Create an AES cipher object
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(b'\x00' * 16), backend=default_backend())
# Decrypt the encrypted audio data
decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
pt = decryptor.update(encrypted_data) + decryptor.finalize()
# Write the decrypted audio data to a file
with wave.open("decrypted_audio.wav", "wb") as f:
    f.setnchannels(1)
    f.setsampwidth(2)
    f.setframerate(44100)
    f.writeframes(pt)
print("Decrypted audio data written to quantum_safe_encrypted_audio.wav")

I thought that the decrypted audio file  will sound as the input original. However its giving noise.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
